# Error while executing code MSB6006 "CL.exeexecuted with code 2

Tags: c, visual-studio

I am getting the following error while executing code on Visual Studio 2019
MSB6006"CL.exe" exited with code 2

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
int a, b, c,x;
x = a / (b - c);

printf("\n Enter values of a,b and c");
scanf_s("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);
printf("\n The value of x is %d", x);
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please tellme what to do?

Comment: When you do `x = a / (b - c);` none of `a`, `b` and `c` have valid values. Move that statement to between the `scanf_s` and the final `printf` (or you could initialize them, eg: `int a=12, b=5, c=3;`).

Comment: You do not need the non-standard header `<conio.h>`

Comment: The error still exists even after i removed it.

Comment: [No error at ideone](https://ideone.com/81GxfL) ... I removed `<conio.h>`, replaced `scanf_s()` and changed the placing of some `'\n'`

Comment: @user3121023: good point! Moving answer here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your order of statements is off.
First assign values to `a`, `b`, and `c`.
Only after use those values in calculations.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a, b, c, x;
    // x = a / (b - c); // NOPE! a, b, and c have no valid values

    printf("Enter values of a, b and c\n");
    scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);
    x = a / (b - c);    // calculation moved here; a, b, and c (hopefully) have valid values now
    printf("The value of x is %d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

**Note: the return value of `scanf()` should be checked to be sure all of `a`, `b`, and `c` have valid values.**

```
if (scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c) != 3) /* error */;
```

<sup>Note 2: I changed your code a little bit: removed non-standard `<conio.h>`, changed the placing of most `'\n'` to be more line-oriented, replaced the optional `scanf_s` (this function may not exist in all C11/C18 implementations).</sup>