# A cause of MSB6006 "CL.exe" exited with code 2 in VS 2019

Tags: c, visual-studio

I have run into a couple cases where I get the CL.exe error listed in the subject line.  My understanding of MSB6006 errors is that these are caused by a bug in the Visual Studio compiler editing routines.  I don't know that it matters, but I'm using VS 2019 Community Edition Version 16.1.6.

In the first case, at least it tells you the cause.

```
//  Warning C6001   Using uninitialized memory 'testbool'.
//  Error   MSB6006 "CL.exe" exited with code 2.

#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    bool testbool;

    if (testbool == true) {

    }
}
```

Below is another example, but there is no indication of the cause:

```
//  Error   MSB6006 "CL.exe" exited with code 2.
bool testFun()
{

}

int main()
{
    bool testBool;
    testBool = testFun();
}
```

Another example, using an `int` that had the same problem:

```
//  Error   MSB6006 "CL.exe" exited with code 2.
bool testFun()
{

}

int main()
{
    int testInt;
    testInt = testFun();
}
```

I also got the error when I tried to print an int that hadn't been initialized.  That problem was already resolved in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57123588/error-while-executing-code-msb6006-cl-exeexecuted-with-code-2), but I didn't see that answer until I posted this.  Also, you don't get the problem if you are just printing a string.

I will answer the question below.

**Update 08/10/19**

I changed the code to `#include stdbool.h`.  Got the same result.  On further looking into it, a C4716 error message flashed for a brief fraction of a second before it was overlayed with the MSB6006 message.  So the problem isn't that the compiler couldn't find the problem, but it's just a problem with the display.

Also included an example of an `int` having the same problem which, like I said, had been resolved in a previous question.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, do what it says and initialize `testBool`.

In the second case, it wasn't obvious to me that you can't specify a return value in the function declaration and then fail to return anything.  Or if you have a `return` statement without specifying a value, you get the message `Error C2561    'testFun': function must return a value` to tell you how to fix the problem instead of the MSB6006 error.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not get a cause here. The warning is not a cause for a build failure as such. And it seems that you're still missing some error messages. I believe the MSB6006 error code means just that the compiler exited with an error code.

If this is indeed a C program it is invalid because the `bool` is a `typedef` for `_Bool` and is introduced only by `#include`ing `<stdbool.h>` which seems not to be present. There ought to be an **error** about *that*

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  You're right about the bug in the code.  I updated the question and found that I had the same problem.  It turned out to just be a problem with a display of the messages.  The error was masked by the MSB6006 overlaying the message about the actual problem.  Still didn't get an error about the `bool` not being defined, though.   Hmmm.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a return to your main, I had this problem not with main but when i forgot a return in a non void function. hope it helps